# Add new lines up to specific row

Tags: awk, sed

Hoping somebody can help me out.

I have large number of files with different number of lines. 
I would like to add new lines in to the files up to specific rows, say 6.

Infile.txt

```
text1 
text2
text3
```

The out file I would like to have is

Outfile.txt

```
text1 
text2
text3 
\n 
\n 
\n
```

Comment: You need to add 6 empty lines to the files irrespective of the line count and content? OR do you have any logic in doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -v r=6 'END{ while((r--)-NR>0) print "" }1' file
```

- `-v r=6` - variable `r` indicating total/maximal number of rows

Comment: Probably not a problem if you're sure about the data, but be careful of a data file with already more than the desired number of lines --- the while loop will be infinite. (Maybe better to compare `(r--)-NR > 0`)

Answer (score 1):

In awk's `END` block, the built-in variable `NR` will contain the row number of the last line of the file. From there it's easy to print the needed number of additional empty rows.

```
$ awk -v lines=6 '1; END {for (i=NR; i<lines; ++i) print ""}' file 
text1
text2
text3



$ awk -v lines=6 '1; END {for (i=NR; i<lines; ++i) print ""}' file | wc -l
6
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the clearest and most obvious way to handle this is to simply loop from the last line number plus 1 to the target number of lines:

```
$ seq 3 | awk -v n=6 '{print} END{for (i=NR+1; i<=n; i++) print ""}'
1
2
3



$
```

You can also count down if you want to save a variable:

```
$ seq 3 | awk -v n=6 '{print} END{while (n-- > NR) print ""}'
1
2
3



$
```

but IMHO that's sacrificing clarity in favor of brevity and not worthwhile.